# How to refactor code inside switch statement using react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to refactor code for a switch statement using react?

I have to list messages for items based on their type like 'created' 'deleted' 'updated' 'commented'. To do so , i use switch statement. Now if there is overflow for the list item i add a expand button. To do so, i created expandable component which is common for all list items.

The code is below,

```
switch (list.type) {
        case 'created': {
            return (
                <Expandable base_height={50}>
                    <List
                        icon={<Svg/>}
                        text={<Text text={' created '} mname={model} 
                        additional_text={some_text}/>}/>
                </Expandable>
            );
         }
         case 'deleted': {
            return (
                <Expandable base_height={50}>
                    <List
                        icon={<Svg/>}
                        text={<Text text={' deleted '} mname={model} 
                        additional_text={some1_text}/>}/>
                </Expandable> 
            );
         }
         case 'udpated':
         {/*ssooooooooooooo on ''''''''''''*/}
         default:
             return null;
 }
```

The above code works. As you see from above code, the Expandable component will be repeated for every case how can i put it outside each case such that i don't have to repeat the same code for each case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each dynamic value, can create a variable and just update the values in respective case statement. At the end use those variables and return the JSX.

Like this:

```
let text = '', mname = '', additional_text='';
switch (list.type) {
    case 'created': {
        text = 'created';
        mname = model;
        additional_text = some_text;
        break;
     }
    case 'deleted': {
        text = 'deleted';
        mname = model;
        additional_text = some1_text;
        break;
     }
    case 'udpated':
        {/*ssooooooooooooo on ''''''''''''*/}
    default:
         return null;
}

return (
    <Expandable base_height={50}>
        <List
            icon={<Svg/>}
            text={<Text text={text} mname={mname} 
            additional_text={additional_text} />}/>
    </Expandable>
);
```